# How to save sed statement (with quotes) in a variable for multiple calls

Tags: bash, sed, escaping, quoting

I have the following pipeline that I use to postprocess some text:

```
sed 's/error/     /g' | sed 's/\+/ /g' | tail -n +6 | ghead -n -1
```

I need to use this pipeline many times, so I want to save all of this in a variable so that I can easily call it later. I have tried several different ways to save the quotes (single quotes, double quotes, escaped quotes, etc.), for example:

```
cleanup='sed '"'"'s/error/     /g'"'"' | sed '"'"'s/\+/ /g'"'"' | tail -n +6 | ghead -n -1'
```

However, so far I haven't found the magic combination.

**Edit ======**

Apparently, my real problem was that I wasn't using `eval`. However, I am still interested in approaches that are more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would work if cleanup was a function, not a string:

```
cleanup() { sed 's/error/     /g' | sed 's/\+/ /g' | tail -n +6 | ghead -n -1; }
```

As an example:

```
$ seq 8 | cleanup
6
7
```

#### Simplification

It looks like the pipeline can be simplified.  If `ghead`, which I am not familiar with, is the same as the usual `head`, then try:

```
cleanup() { sed '1,5d; $d; s/error/     /g; s/\+/ /g'; }
```

This works as follows:

- `1,5 d` deletes lines one through 5.  This replaces `tail -n +6`.
- `$d` deletes the last line.  This replaces `head -n -1`.
- The two substitute commands remain the same but are combined into this single invocation of sed.

#### Non-GNU sed (BSD, Mac OSX)

The above was tested on GNU sed.   NeronLeVelu reports that other sed versions may require newline characters after the delete commands.  In that case, using bash's `$'...'` feature, try:

```
cleanup() { sed $'1,5d\n $d\n s/error/     /g; s/\+/ /g'; }
```

Or, try:

```
cleanup() { sed -e '1,5d' -e '$d' -e's/error/     /g' -e 's/\+/ /g'; }
```

Comment: very good use of sed at once. In case of posix, just put 1 `d` action per line (following instruction on the line are ignored, in most of the case, after a `d`)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Thanks for the info!  I added that to the answer.  I have also had reports that separating the string into `-e command` satisfies BSD sed.  (If I had access to such a platform, I would try it myself but I don't.)

Answer (score 1):

Just surrounding your whole command with double quotes should work, to execute the stored variable use eval:

```
cleanup="sed 's/error/ /g' | sed 's/\+/ /g' | tail -n +6 | ghead -n -1"
eval $cleanup
```

Normally in bash there is no need to escape single quotes inside a double quoted string and vice versa.

Comment: I get `sed: 1: "'s/error/": invalid command code '`. Nevermind!! I was missing the `eval`, which seems to have been my problem all along. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
cleanup="`cat << EOF
sed 's/error/     /g' | sed 's/\+/ /g' | tail -n +6 | ghead -n -1
EOF`"
```

With this you can put any text between the two EOF and it won't be interpreted by bash

```
seq 8 | eval $cleanup
```